# In Hadoop Command Line, How do I save all the commands I used as a log in any format for my subsequent reference. Thanks.

Tags: logging, hadoop, command-line

In Hadoop Command Line, what is the code to save all the commands I used in a log (in any format that maintains history of transactions performed) for subsequent reference. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? At least googling for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a direct hadoop command to do that but you can always use [ttyrec](http://0xcc.net/ttyrec/index.html.en) to record the commands you run.